# Is there a sample repo for custom tslint rules available?

Tags: tslint

I created a custom rule in my local tslint repo. However it would be better if I could create my own repo with my code in it and just reference tslint from there.

I have followed the steps from [this site](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/2016/03/31/sharable-configurations-rules.html). This works if I manually copy it over. But with this setup I can't test/debug things out.

Since I want to be able debug the code and have lint/fix files I created a different setup. Here again I didn't find how to debug my code. At this point I just test with `tslint --test` ...), but I want to be able to debug if an error happens.

Further `tslint --test` fails. It is as if my code just doesn't get run (actual is different from expected (it's always the same as the input)), while the same code in the tslint project (where I started) does work. And when using it as a npm package in another project, my rule again doesn't seem to run (even though it is found by configuration).

I'm a newbie at this, and I'm doing something wrong.  I was hoping to find a sample repo that I can start from fresh. The repo would have:

- custom-rules
- test.lint and test.fix files that can be run and debugged for a custom rule
- is setup correctly to be used as an npm package, so that the custom rules can be used in other projects.

At this point I did not find a repo like this that included all these properties and still is simple enough to wrap my brain around.